# How to get selected shipping rate for logged in and guest customer

Tags: shipping

I am trying to get selected shipping rate for logged in and guest customer, for this I am using :

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

try with `$this->_checkoutSession->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();`
This should return the code of the shipping method, or null if there is no shipping method selected yet.

Comment: it is always returning null.